# If $v$ and $w$ are differentiable functions and $v=Aw$, is the matrix-valued function $A$ differentiable?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

Let $U\subset\mathbf{R}^m$ be open and let
\begin{equation}
v,w\colon U\to\mathbf{R}^n
\end{equation}
be differentiable functions. In addition, assume there is a matrix-valued function
\begin{equation}
A\colon U\to\mathbf{R}^{n\times n}
\end{equation}
such that
\begin{equation}
w=Av.
\end{equation}
Equivalently,
\begin{equation}
w_k=\sum_{l=1}^nA_{kl}v_l,
\end{equation}
for all $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Is $A$ differentiable? In other words, are all entries $A_{kl}\colon U\to\mathbf{R}$ differentiable? In case it helps, you can assume that $A(x)$ is invertible for all $x\in U$.

Comment: I'm not well-versed in the subject matter here, but if this was the case then wouldn't $v = w = 0$ imply that any matrix-valued function is differentiable? That doesn't seem right to me

Comment: @StephenDonovan That's a good point, thank you! I'm reading a proof that seems to assume this, but maybe I have missed some additional assumptions, I'll check that.

Comment: perhaps something along these lines is being used: If $A$ is a matrix-valued function such that for every vector $v$ (belonging to a spanning set of $\Bbb{R}^n$), the evaluated mapping $x\mapsto A(x)\cdot v$ is smooth; then $A$ is smooth.

Comment: @peek-a-boo To be precise, I was looking at the equation $w=\rho(g)^{-1}v$, where $\rho\colon G\to\mathrm{GL}(V)$ is a representation. However, it turned out that $g\colon U\to G$ is assumed to be differentiable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stephen Donovan pointed out in the comments, the answer is no, because this would imply that any matrix-valued function is differentiable (by considering the case $v=w=0$).

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to ask if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable functions and if $f=h\circ g$ then, is $h$ differentiable? The answer is **no** in general, by example the real-valued map $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R},\, x\mapsto  |x^2|$ is differentiable, also is the map $g: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R},\, x \mapsto x^2$, but the function $h:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R},\, x\mapsto |x|$ is not differentiable.

The previous counter-example can be generalized to any dimension.